# FullCalendar show time in cell on hover

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement in fullcalendar.io small feature.

I need my calendar show me what time is it when I hover specified cell in weekView or dayView.
For now I get to point when calendar shows me this time but only in whole row using this code in viewRender method:

```
$('#calendar').find('.fc-slats').find('[class="fc-widget-content"]').hover(
function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    var time = tr.find('td.fc-axis.fc-time.fc-widget-content').find("span").text();
    $(this).append('<td class="temp_cell" style="border: 0px; width:5px;">'+time+'</td>');
},          
function() {                        
    $(this).children('.temp_cell').remove();
});
```

Here is shipped of my code: [jsfiddle.net/przemekp/w71rd9yz/](https://jsfiddle.net/przemekp/w71rd9yz/)

Can anyone know how to show this in cell per specified day week.

Comment: you want to show this within the hovered cell, or as a popover?

Comment: Inside the cell like in my example.

Answer (score 1):

me too, I was looking for a way to this functionality. 
After many hours of coding with lot of try / error, here is my technique :

first of all, my fullcalendar object is named "semaine". (I'm french...)
I'm using a 'agenda' view (with all days of week displayed)

Here is the definition of my fullcalendar object :

    `$('#semaine').fullCalendar({
        ...
        select: function(ehDeb, ehFin, jsEvent, vue) { 
            eraseAllCellTime($('#semaine'));
            ....
        },
        eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            eraseAllCellTime($('#semaine'));
        },

        ....
    });`

Just after this definition, I've these three callback functions overrided :

```
$('#semaine').find('.fc-slats').find('[class="fc-widget-content"]').mouseover(
    function(mouseEvent) {
        displayCellTime($('#semaine'), this, mouseEvent);
    }
);
$('#semaine').find('.fc-slats').find('[class="fc-widget-content"]').mouseenter(
    function(mouseEvent) {
        displayCellTime($('#semaine'), this, mouseEvent);
    }
);
$('#semaine').mouseleave(
    function() {
        eraseAllCellTime($('#semaine'));
    }
);
```

and now the two functions :

```
function eraseAllCellTime(calendar) {
    calendar.find('.fc-slats').find('[class="fc-widget-content"]').each(function() {
        $(this).empty();
    });
}

function displayCellTime(calendar, tdAllDays, mouseEvent) {
    // We remove all td cell contents
    eraseAllCellTime(calendar);
    // and we display the good cell
    var tr = $(tdAllDays).parent();
    var time = tr.find('td.fc-axis.fc-time.fc-widget-content').find("span").text();
    var dayColumns = calendar.find('th.fc-day-header');
    var html = '<table class="dailycolumncutting">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var mouseX = mouseEvent.clientX;
    var mouseY = mouseEvent.clientY;
    for(var d = 0; d < dayColumns.size(); d++) {
        var day = $(dayColumns[d]);
        var offset = day.offset();
        var width  = day.width();
        if (mouseX >= offset.left && mouseX <= offset.left+width) {
            html += '<td class="hovered">' + day.data("date") + '<br />' + time + '</td>';                            
        } else {
            html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
    }
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '</table>';
    $(tdAllDays).empty();
    $(tdAllDays).append(html);
}
```

and finally, the css definition :

```
.dailycolumncutting td {
    width: 100%;
}
.dailycolumncutting td.hovered {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff000055;
}
```

you can surely improve that, but it can give you the basics for your need ...